# Facebook Graph Api has missing results when searching for places

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When using facebook graph API to search around a specific location, I came around a specific problem.

This is they query where I can easily reproduce this:

```
search?type=place&center=40.7315898,-8.3739449&distance=1000
```

(showing 2 results at the time of writing)

When I search without query I get some results. But I know others are missing.
If I query with a simple `q=bar`, I have more results than without query.

```
search?type=place&q=bar&center=40.7315898,-8.3739449&distance=1000
```

(showing 7 results at the time of writing)

Has anyone come across this and found a solution ?

Comment: Search functionality in Graph API is rudimentary at best. Results may be tailored to the user who’s access token is used, and delivers different results for different people. There is no guarantee for “completeness” of search results.

Comment: In this case, and i should have mentioned, I'm using an app access token.
But by what you're saying, there is no way to ensure that any search will get me all results, no matter what ?